# Perforce Submit/Commit Condition

Tags: version-control, perforce

I use the perforce GUI client.  I'm wondering what's the easiest way to have perforce not submit a change list when clicking "submit" if the description of that submission does not contain a particular set of words (entered by the submitter/committer)?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a Trigger on the server. It is a script that runs on the server that you can make to check the comment. see more info here

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/06_scripting.html

Comment: And you can find examples of triggers in the Perforce Public Depot: http://public.perforce.com/wiki/Welcome_to_the_Public_Depot